# Query on meta values and post title

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I need some help with my search function.
What I want is a search function that search on the post title and on my meta values.

The meta values works but how can I add the post title to this query?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'catalog',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'catalog_item_creator',
            'value'   => $_GET['searchtext'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'catalog_item_sku',
            'value'   => $_GET['searchtext'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        'relation' => 'OR',
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: There is no `'title'` parameter for this, but you can get the post ID from post title. Also, the specified post will be already of the right _post type_. See [`get_page_by_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/).

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209196/wordpress-query-all-posts-that-start-with-a-special-symbol-not-a-z